# Streamlit with Colab

Tags: python, dataset, google-colaboratory, dashboard, streamlit

I am using streamlit with Colab. The cell is running continuously but the link it sharing is not working. Is there any solution for that?

[image]

I am not getting any error. Just link is not working. Both links are given in the above image `http://172.28.0.12:8501/` I want to run the streamlit app on Colab.

Comment: This link should be helpful : https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-launch-streamlit-app-from-google-colab-notebook/42399

Comment: I have tried it. But its not working.